# Getting scaling from a 2D Matrix

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix [a b c d tx ty] that I would like to get the scaling (X and Y) out of. So far I have used the following formulae:

scale_x :$= \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$

scale_y :$= \sqrt{c^2 + d^2}$

This works pretty well except for one problem:
Negative scalings (e.g. [-1, 1]) get lost.

Is there a better formula that preserves the signum of the scaling?

Comment: What do you call the scaling for 2D linear transformations?

Comment: Uh, what is the scaling?  Do you mean the [eigenvalues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue)?  That won't calculate the eigenvalues correctly.